# Intel XDK - How to navigate to page with bootstrap NavBar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, intel-xdk

How do I navigate to page with bootstrap NavBar(in **intel xdk**) ?

I want to navigate to ***login-page*** by clicking **Login** in navbar.

I've tried using onclick events, but still not working.

[image]